# Java:: process builder: bash script: returned fileName is correct but fileReader throws a FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, linux, file, sh

Can anyone please explain why this `FileNotFoundException` happens?

I am trying to get a last modified `file_name` from remote linux and this way works and returns a file name:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
ProcessBuilder pbSetPermissions = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -t " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + " | head -n 1");
String fileName = IOUtils.toString(pb.start().getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(fileName);
File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
String filePath = folder + "/" + DOWNLOADS_DIR + "/" + fileName;
pbSetPermissions.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "chmod 777 " + filePath);
pbSetPermissions.start();
System.out.println(filePath);
```

Also, it set the correct permissions to file and I can read this file e.g. using 'nano'

But then, when I try to read and parse this file from Java fileReader:

```
FileReader filereader = new FileReader(filePath);
```

I always get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory)
```

See screens:

[image]

[image]

==================

I have resolved this problem and got last `Modified File Name` another way:

```
File file = findLastModified(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + DOWNLOADS_DIR);
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + DOWNLOADS_DIR);

public static File findLastModified (String sdir) {
    File dir = new File(sdir);
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        Optional<File> opFile = Arrays.stream(dir.listFiles(File::isFile))
                .max(Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified));
        if (opFile.isPresent()){
            return opFile.get();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

====================

But I am still confused why the first way with bash script is not working. It seems like there are some hidden symbols in file name? Or something with encoding? Because from what I see the file path is correct.

Comment: `ls` and `head` output lines, so the filename you read would have a trailing linefeed

Comment: oh, exactly! thanks! :)